# How to use closures in validation component in Symfony2?

Tags: validation, symfony, annotations, closures

Would you share with me an example how to use closures in validation component in Symfony2?

I use this code to validate $prop:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class A
{
    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Choice(choices = {"value1", "value2"})
     */
    private $prop;
}
```

I want to use closure here as shown in [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Choice.html#callback) with "callback" option. I've googled for a while but haven't found any examples yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to use a closure you'll have to define your validation metadata using PHP (as opposed to YAML, XML or annotations). For an example, take a look at the "PHP" tab of the first example on the page you linked to. It uses `loadValidatorMetadata`.

Here's how it would look with a callback set:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Mapping\ClassMetadata;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Choice;

class Author
{
    protected $gender;

    public static function loadValidatorMetadata(ClassMetadata $metadata)
    {
        $metadata->addPropertyConstraint('gender', new Choice(
            'message' => 'Choose a valid gender',
            'callback' => function () {
                return array('male', 'female');
            },
        ));
    }
}
```

As you can see, it doesn't really work very well. The main issue is that the static `loadValidatorMetadata` method does not really have any access to the outside world.

If you insist on using closures you could create a separate implementation of the `Symfony\Component\Validator\Mapping\Loader\LoaderInterface`. But honestly, the easiest is to just use callback with an instance method name, as the example shows with `getGenders`.

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer. It doesn't look like closure in the usual sense. You are right, it is easier to use a simple callback here, little bit strange.. Again, thanks!